# Excel cell limit - Different results for same scenario

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have numbers in my excel cell which looks like as shown below

[image]

I would like to use `Len` and `Left` formula to the numbers present

1. Why does `Len` function returns 15 as output for the 1st row? It has to be `21` without decimal points and `23` with decimal points?
2. When I apply `LEFT` to extract 1st 10 digits why does it return output as `5.71011899` instead of `5710118995`
3. How come the 2nd row is working fine and not the first row?

The format of the cells for both the rows are same.

Can you help me with the above questions, please?

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using? Why do you have so many tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LEN function expects a string but you're supplying it a number, which is usually fine because Excel will convert the number to a string automatically. *This appears to happen without Excel looking at the number format (if any) applied to the cell.*

The first number is the larger of the two and appears to be being passed to LEN as  `5.710118995E+20` (15 characters) whereas the second number is a magnitude smaller and appears to be passed to LEN as `57101189950000000000` (20 characters).

This is presumably happening because of the way Excel internally represents numbers differently depending on their scale and precision (integers versus floating point).

The easiest way to avoid the arbitrary conversions is to handle them yourself:

```
=LEFT(TEXT(CELL, "0"), 10)
```

or better yet for numbers of this magnitude, stick with scientific notation:

```
=left(TEXT(CELL, "0.0000000000E+00"), 10)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Upvoted. Will keep you updated after I try

Comment: Hi @Mike Fitzpatrick - One quick question.  May I kindly check with you on why 1st row is stored as scientific and the second row is stored as the same number (full number as is). Inspite both cells being number format

Comment: `microsft article` linked doesn't take me to Microsoft page

Comment: Sorry, @TheGreat. I meant [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-au/office/troubleshoot/excel/floating-point-arithmetic-inaccurate-result).

Comment: Thanks, Can I also check what does `LEFT (TEXT(CELL, "0"))` do? Meaning that "0" COMPONENT

Comment: I understand that's a format code but what does `0` do to the text function

Comment: Because when I apply `TEXT(H8, "000000")` this to a number `1234`, I get the output as `001234`. Hence didn't understand how this works. Can help me please?

Comment: I understand it addes leading zeroes to make the result match the format length. In this case, by adding single `0`, what does it do to the number that we have? It does nothing because our number length is anyway higher than 1 ( single `0`)

Comment: Passing "0" as the second parameter to TEXT() means format as a number without decimal places, separators or exponentiation - essentially as an integer. Passing "00000" means format as an integer without decimals places, separators or exponentiation AND display leading zeros if the number is less than 10000.